# CSS Borders in list items

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a problem using borders in list items. 
I wanted to make all the elements in the <li> have borders but the <li> exceeding the width of the window loses their border on the right side. How can I fix this?
Here is the sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmLp86dy/

```
.line-row {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.line-row li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #737373;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 0px;
}

.line-row li:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li.success {
    background: #00ff00;
}

ul li.delayed {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outline instead of border and you no more need to remove the `border-right`. Simply increase the `margin-top` since outline aren't considering in the height calculation and position:

```css
.line-row {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.line-row li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    background: #737373;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li.success {
    background: #00ff00;
}

ul li.delayed {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline" style="display: inline-block;">
  <ul class="batch line-row">
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
    <li class="success"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```